Tooltip missing when copying geometries across files in Google Earth Engine
In Google Earth Engine, I am trying to copy geometries from one project to another (thousands of points), and the tooltip to convert the geometries does not come up when I copy into a fresh script.
The post linked below had the same issue, and the suggested fix did not work for me.
Reg Google Earth Engine code editor suggestion tooltip
My script is linked here (with a sample below):
https://code.earthengine.google.com/57fa1ff585fd8ccf90e73b9f342bcaa8
var campsJuly19 = ee.ImageCollection("projects/project1-obleodemandre/assets/CBCamps_July2019"),
    campsMarch19 = ee.ImageCollection("projects/project1-obleodemandre/assets/CBCamps_Mar19"),
    campBoundaries = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/project1-obleodemandre/assets/campOutlines"),
    tree = 
    /* color: #0f6a0f */
    /* shown: false */
    ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([92.16519292383533, 21.208364972573417]),
            {
              "class": 0,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([92.16607268839222, 21.20861502692851]),
            {
              "class": 0,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([92.16571134154242, 21.208970070803094]),
            {
              "class": 0,
              "system:index": "2"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([92.16346898166628, 21.209547372464105]),
            {
              "class": 0,
              "system:index": "3"
            }),]);

